# arithmetic progression, problem.

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

A company will distribute $\$46,000$ in bonuses to their top ten vendors. The last winner from the list will receive $\$1000$ and the difference in money between sellers on classifieds should be constant. Find the bonus for each worker.

You know how to solve this?

Comment: Use `\$12345` to show \$12345. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: ohh thanks, I do not know the bbcodes well. Thanks, it's a huge step.

Answer (score 1):

The terms in a ten term arithmetic progression are $a, a+d, a+2d \dots a+9d$.  Add them up.  What is $a$?  What is $d$?

Comment: a10 is the position 10 in the ten workers, that worker received the minimun amount of money, a1 received the maximum amount for was a good seller

Comment: That is fine, but you have not used the fact that the differences are the same.  That is where I got that it is an arithmetic progression.  Without that, you can't solve the problem.